# Shortest Word in a list - JS

Tags: javascript

I need to return the shortest word in the list of three. If there are ties, it should return the first word in the parameters list.

Here's my function so far:

```
function short(w1, w2, w3) {
  var arr = word1.concat(word2, word3);
  arr.split(",");

  arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.length <= b.length ? a : b;
  });
}

var output = short('a', 'bee', 'gracele');
console.log(output); // --> MUST RETURN 'a'
```

Right now this one doesn't work. Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: wrong syntax of reduce, using word1 while passing w1, not returning the output of reduce are to name a few.

Comment: @binariedMe - There's nothing wrong with the syntax of `.reduce()` used here. (Not returning its result is obviously a big problem though.)

Comment: @nnnnnn I'd say that passing undefined as second parameter will thrown an error for a.length as a for first iteration would be undefined

Comment: @binariedMe - `.reduce()`'s second argument is optional: if not supplied the first iteration passes the first two array elements to the callback (instead of passing the accumulator and the first array element).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close with what you've written, but you made a few mistakes.

First, you're trying to use `word`, `word2`, `word3`. None of which are defined. I'm assuming this is a typo and you actually meant `w1`, `w2`, `w3`.

Second, you're trying to concatenate the words and split on `,`, but you're not adding a comma into the string.

Finally, you're not returning the result of your `reduce` function call.

Fix those up, streamline the process by converting the function `arguments` immediately to an array and you have this:

```
function short(/* any number of args */) {
  var words = [].slice.call(arguments);

  return words.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return a.length <= b.length ? a : b;
  });
}
```

Combining the idea suggested by @JaredFarrish, you could modify the function to accept individual words, or an array of words.

```
function short(words) {
  words = Array.isArray(words) ? words : [].slice.call(arguments);

  return words.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return a.length <= b.length ? a : b;
  });
}

console.log(short('this', 'is', 'a', 'sentence'));  // 'a'
console.log(short('this is a sentence'.split(' ')));  // 'a'
```

Comment: is more supported reduce or sort? 
 `[].slice.call(arguments).sort((x,y)=>x.length-y.length)[0]` too lazy to check, sorry

Comment: @Eineki - I don't understand what you're asking? Are you suggesting to use `sort` instead of `reduce`?

Comment: In theory you could sort and `.pop()` or `.shift()` to get the largest/smallest. Will that `<=` predicate the first shortest match?

Comment: I don't think you could use `.sort()` because you couldn't guarantee it would break ties the way the OP wants.

Comment: Agreed. If you had the sentence `b a good person`, using sort would return `a`, rather than `b`.

Comment: @fubar - Your sort example seems to be based on an alphabetic sort, but to find the shortest you'd have to sort on length in which case "b" *could* be returned before "a". But might not be in all cases, because JS's `.sort()` method isn't required to use a "stable" sort algorithm.

Comment: @fubar I used to use `sort()` with an helper function as `reduce()` was not available on older ie versions. You have to specify a sort function based on length rather than alphabetical order but you obtain the same result (less efficient solution though).

Comment: @nnnnnn Actually I think the sorting algorithm are stable in all the major browser (didn't know or check this before) but to play on the safe side we can disambiguate the equal case when sorting: `[].slice.call(arguments).sort((x,y)=>x.length-y.length>0?1:-1)[0]`.

Comment: @nnnnnn Reference: ECMAscript 262 /3rd ed Dec1999, section 15.4.4.11 says: `Array.prototype.sort (comparefn)`
The elements of this array are sorted. The sort is not necessarily stable (that is, **elements that compare
equal do not necessarily remain in their original order**). If comparefn is not undefined, it should be a
function that accepts two arguments x and y and returns a negative value if x < y, **zero if x = y**, or a
positive value if x > y.` But this is just pedantry without useful implications, better use reduce!

Comment: @Eineki - you can't make an unstable sort stable by changing the logic in the comparator, because when the comparator is called it doesn't know the original indices of the elements, it only knows the values of an arbitrary two elements at a time. Although I suspect you are right that the major browsers probably do use stable algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

I made the function very generic by using `arguments` parameter to loop through all the strings passed to the `short` function, so you can pass in any number of strings into it.

There are multiple wonderful answers using `reduce` here, so here's an answer that does not rely on `reduce`.

If you have multiple strings of the shortest length, it will only return the first shortest string found, like what you asked for.

```
function short(w1, w2, w3) {
  var shortestWord = arguments[0];
  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    if (arguments[i].length < shortestWord.length) {
      shortestWord = arguments[i];
    }
  }
  return shortestWord;
}

var output = short('a', 'bee', 'gracele');
console.log(output); // Returns 'a'
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a function (note that `a.length > b.length ? b : a` preservers the order):

```js
console.log(['a', 'bee', 'gracele'].reduce((a, b) => {
    return a.length > b.length ? b : a;
}));
```

But if you do, write it to accept an array:

```js
function shortest(words) {
    return words.reduce((a, b) => {
        return a.length > b.length ? b : a;
    });
}

console.log(shortest(['a', 'bee', 'gracele']));
```

The reason I say "pass it in" instead of slicing arguments or splitting a string is that that's not really the point of the function. Do that when you call it and it'll be more flexible:

```
shortest('longer list of words with varying lengths'.split(' '));
```

And first shortest match:

```js
function shortest(words) {
    return words.reduce((a, b) => {
        return a.length > b.length ? b : a;
    });
}

console.log(shortest('longer list of words as with varying lengths'.split(' ')));
```

And, y'know, if it HAS to have three arguments (non-variable), then that's also very easy:

```js
function shortest(a, b, c) {
    return [a,b,c].reduce((d, e) => {
        return e.length > d.length ? d : e;
    });
}

console.log(shortest('which','is','shortest'));
```

Comment: The idea of just splitting the sentence is a good one. Have an upvote. I think it'd be advantageous to be able to do this, and to be able to pass individual words.

Comment: I thought about that, `shortest('word')`. I think it still ends up in the same scenario though, `shortest('word'.split(''))` and the `shortest()` function doesn't have to guess; the knowledge of the request belongs to the caller, not the callee, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a little more verbose...

```js
function shortest(words) {
  return words.slice(1).reduce((acc, val) => {
    return acc.length > val.length ? val : acc;
  }, words[0]);
}

console.log(shortest('a bee garcele'.split(' ')));

console.log(shortest(['a', 'bee', 'garcele']));
```

Comment: You don't need the `.slice(1)` and `words[0]` part: the `.reduce()` method's second argument is optional and it will work as shown in the question (it was the other parts of the OP's code that were the problem).

Answer (score 0):

```
function shortestWord (str) {
   const newArrayList = str.split(" ");

   let count = 1;

   let currentWordCount = newArrayList[0];

   for (let I = 0; I < newArrayList.length; i++) {
 
     if (currentWordCount < newArrayList[count]) {

        currentWordCount = newArrayList[i];

          count++;
     } else if (currentWordCount>=newArrayList[count]) {

        count++;
     }
   }

   return currentWordCount;
 }
```